# Change the syntax highlighting when exporting to HTML

Tags: org-mode

I am using Org mode to write some tutorials for myself on a topic where I weave the explanation and code samples into the same document. This document will then be exported to HTML to distribute to some colleagues.

Currently, I am able to export my org file to HTML and get syntax highlighting for code snippets. However, I don't like the default syntax highlighting provided in the exported HTML file. The background is white, the string color is a pale pink which tends to be indistinguishable from the white background.

[image]

How can I change this color scheme? I would like to have a scheme similar to the one used on, say, [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#babys-first-functions) page.

Note that I want the syntax highlighting customized in the exported HTML and not inside an Emacs buffer itself which I am perfectly happy with,.